# Adding markers/places to Qt QML Maps?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

Good day ! I am designing a **Qt-based GUI platform** that *displays a map* and allows users to *add markers/pins* on top of the map.

I am rendering the map in a QtQuickWidget using the following QML:

```
Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
    name: "osm"
}
```

I want to allow the user to **add an interactive pin on the map** using a button on a form. The user can press and hold a point on the map which will open the form, where the user can name the place and press **OK**.

[Example of interactive pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jc0r.png)

*Example of what I want to achieve:* https://webmshare.com/play/5EXV8

---

1. I have tried using QQmlComponent and QQuickView but I was
   unsuccessful
   [http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html]
2. Another way is to add objects within QML itself using *MapItems* but
       this is very unintuitive. This is what my map.qml looks like:
       https://gist.github.com/blackvitriol/7941688d6362162888630a28c79f8cd9

Project Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h38pZ.jpg

**Can someone tell me how to allow the user to press and hold left click on the map, then add a marker to that point ?**

Comment: I mean that it does not make sense to create a QML file with lots of objects (markers) being added to the same file. I have tried to add a MapCircle item to my Map.qml but even that is not visible.

Comment: added project structure and map.qml

Answer (score 9):

A possible solution is to use `MapItemView` and create a model that stores the coordinates:

**markermodel.h**

```
#ifndef MARKERMODEL_H
#define MARKERMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QGeoCoordinate>

class MarkerModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QAbstractListModel::QAbstractListModel;
    enum MarkerRoles{positionRole = Qt::UserRole + 1};

    Q_INVOKABLE void addMarker(const QGeoCoordinate &coordinate){
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        m_coordinates.append(coordinate);
        endInsertRows();
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override{
        Q_UNUSED(parent)
        return m_coordinates.count();
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override{
        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_coordinates.count())
            return QVariant();
        if(role== MarkerModel::positionRole)
            return QVariant::fromValue(m_coordinates[index.row()]);
        return QVariant();
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const{
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[positionRole] = "position";
        return roles;
    }

private:
    QList<QGeoCoordinate> m_coordinates;
};

#endif // MARKERMODEL_H
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        id: mapview
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
        zoomLevel: 14

        MapItemView{
            model: markerModel
            delegate: mapcomponent
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: mapcomponent
        MapQuickItem {
            id: marker
            anchorPoint.x: image.width/4
            anchorPoint.y: image.height
            coordinate: position

            sourceItem: Image {
                id: image
                source: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png"
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressAndHold:  {
            var coordinate = mapview.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
            markerModel.addMarker(coordinate)
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "markermodel.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickWidget>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QQuickWidget w;
    MarkerModel model;
    w.rootContext()->setContextProperty("markerModel", &model);
    w.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

<sub>The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/49344638).</sub>

Comment: Wow ! Very impressive. This seems like it might be the solution. 
I am using  a QQuickWidget using the Qt Design tab and not defined in the main.cpp. Can you please advice me to how to set the w.rootContext()->setContextProperty("markerModel", &model); for a QQuickWidget that I have implemented using the GUI Designer ? I tried to reference to it using ui->edge_map->rootContext()->setContextProperty("markerModel", &model); but it doesn't work.

Comment: ../mainwindow.cpp:32:32: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class QQmlContext’
     ui->edge_map->rootContext()->setContextProperty("markerModel", model);
                                ^

Comment: i am working on it right now, will get it done then accept the answer :)

Comment: Okay, the map has a empty overlay of marker model now, but I haven't understood how you have defined the markers (data types) ? It is a very complex answer, and thank you for your effort.

Comment: This approach is not very useful because, the markers get erased and are not stored into hard memory. Furthermore, the markers cannot be activated by clicking on them.

Comment: The correct link is : https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/49344638